# what is the use of buffer size in socket?

Tags: linux, sockets

I am learn about the ping command implementation. In that I had a one doubt. The doubt is

I know the socket buffer is for how many bytes transfer at a time in the socket.
But how the ping command manages the socket buffer size.

```
$ ping -S 300 -s 400 google.com
PING google.com (216.58.197.46) 400(428) bytes of data.
72 bytes from maa03s20-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.197.46): icmp_req=1 ttl=56 (truncated)
72 bytes from maa03s20-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.197.46): icmp_req=2 ttl=56 (truncated)
72 bytes from maa03s20-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.197.46): icmp_req=3 ttl=56 (truncated)
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 40.231/41.500/42.408/0.924 ms
```

In the above ping command I was given the socket buffer size as 300 and the single packet size as 400. The socket buffer size is 300 only. But the the ping transfer the 400 bytes at a time in that socket. How it is possible. 
At the same time the received packet size is only 72. Why that is only 72.

Can any one please explain me.

Answer (score 0):

The ping request only used/required 72 bytes of data. This is within your 300 buffer size (limit) and your 400 byte packet size. The ICMP packet likely contained 64 data bytes and 8 header bytes resulting in a 72 byte packet.

Since the ICMP packet only needed 72 bytes it isn't going to add unnecessary data to meet your 400 byte packet size.